# SharePoint get_item("my_note_field") is null for some and not for others

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

I have built a SharePoint app that allows users to construct a query, run it, and export the results as an xlxs file. It seems that all the parts of the app work exactly as I intended, with the exception of the fields where `typeAsString = Note`.

For many of the results (not all) these fields are blank. It seems to be because `get_item("my_note_field")` is returning null.

Why would `get_item()` return **null** for some and not for others?

**Please note:** I have confirmed from the source list that there are notes in the list items I am getting returned from the query.

**Update:** I have found that using the `get_versions()` method on a list item returns a value of 2 for every list item that is returning a `null` value. The list items that return the note field value all have a `get_versions()` return of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the the note field was displaying a `null` value was because there was more than one version of the comment field. When I used `item.get_item("my_note_field")` it was returning the most recent note. I needed to load the previous versions of the column in order to get the correct field value.

Answer (score 0):

You’d better provide detailed solution so we could try to research.
My test code,it works well:

```
 <script>
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
    var context =  SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
       var web = context.get_web();  
       var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("test");  
       var query = new SP.CamlQuery(); 
       context.load(list);  
       query.set_viewXml(”<View><Query></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='my_note_field' /></ViewFields></View>”);  
       var items = list.getItems(query);  
       context.load(list);  
       context.load(items, 'Include(my_note_field)');  
       context.executeQueryAsync(  
        Function.createDelegate(this, function () {  
            var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();  
            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {  
                var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();  
                console.log(currentListItem.get_item("my_note_field"));             
            }  
        }),  
       Function.createDelegate(this, fail)  
     );  
    })
    function fail(){}
    </script>
```

Comment: Good morning, thank you for your response. This is very similar to the code that I have in my project. It seems that the note fields that are returning null have something in common; they all return a value of 2 when I use the get_versions() method. The list items that show the content from the note field correctly return a value of 1 when the get_versions() method is used.